# Why the screen turns black?

Tags: drivers, graphics, suse, amd-graphics

I'm using a Vega8/RX/RG laptop. When I try to change the screen resolution it only shows a black screen, then returns to the previous resolution.

The driver is `amdgpu`, the distro is openSUSE Tumbleweed.

I have been trying to change to 1440x900 using `xrandr` and `arandr`.

Is there any way to make it use the custom resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you're hitting a driver error in which case you might try installing the freshest available stable kernel which is 5.8.3 at the moment or your monitor doesn't actually support the desired resolution.

Also make sure you've checked `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `dmesg` for errors. I suspect you'll find your answer there.

Comment: And how can  be confirmed if the monitor support it or not?  Thats why I use Tumbleweed since there is a constant update in it, it is running kernel 5.8.1

Comment: Could you at least post the tail of your X.org log?